# Grails domain associations with cascading save enabled and transactions

Tags: grails, transactions, grails-orm, cascading

Say we have the following two domain classes:

```
class Book {
    static belongsTo = [author: Author]
}
class Author {
    static hasMany = [books: Book]
}
```

No if an `Author` is initialized with several books and `Author.save()` is called then the save cascades to `Book` and both `Author` and `Book` instances are saved into db.

However I can't find anywhere in documentation if the mentioned operation will be done transactionally or not.

Any idea?
Any resource to check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on **where the save is done**. Is it done in a controller action marked as transactional? Is it in a service which uses transactions by default? Or is it done somewhere else where there is no transaction.

If the save is done somewhere that supports transaction (two examples above) then yes, it will be. Otherwise, no it won't be.

Comment: Ok clear,  so `save()` method does not create a transaction inside it even if the cascading save is enabled

Comment: Correct. It does not.

Comment: Do you know any official resource about this fact ? Can't find anywhere